# linq to entity database not updating

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I am creating a program in C# winforms which keeps track of in game stats and passes them to the DB. The code I've written isn't throwing any errors and has updated the first entry on two occasions. On every other occasion it has run through the code and done nothing. As far as I can see it looks right and I can't find any help elsewhere.

The data has been stored in an array for each player. Before updating it cycles through a loop selecting each player from the array and passes the details to the corresponding entry in the DB. The DB is then meant to update before looping through and updating the next player.

Here is my code:

```
public void updateDB()
    {
        //WHY ARE YOU NOT UPDATING THE DB?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>
        using (var context = new BeerPongEntities6())
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt16(Players[i].playerID);
                var query = from p in context.PlayerDetails
                    where p.PlayerID == ID
                    select p;

                var playerUpdate = query.FirstOrDefault();

                playerUpdate.TotalShots += Players[i].totalShots;
                playerUpdate.TotalCups += Players[i].totalCups;
                playerUpdate.TotalMisses += Players[i].totalMisses;
                playerUpdate.TotalBounceShots += Players[i].totalBounce;
                playerUpdate.TotalBounceCups += Players[i].totalBounceCups;
                playerUpdate.TotalOverthrows += Players[i].overthrows;                 

                playerUpdate.GamesPlayed += 1;

                //if statements to determine whether you won or lost
                if ((winner == 1)) //Players 1 and 3 (Team1)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 2)
                    {
                        playerUpdate.GamesWon += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerUpdate.GamesLost += 1;
                    }
                }
                if (winner == 2) //players 2 and 4 (Team2)
                    {
                        if (i == 1 || i == 3)
                        {
                            playerUpdate.GamesWon += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            playerUpdate.GamesLost += 1;
                        }
                    } 
                    //Save the stats to the DB
                        context.SaveChanges();
            }
                    myPlayer.allPlayers();
                    MessageBox.Show("Stats Database updated");
    }
```

Comment: You only have 3 iterations in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the database did not like to update the properties that were NULL. I changed the DB entries to all have a default of 0. Once I had done this the properties updated.